# How does one self-learn mathematics without access to solutions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, probability, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have completed high-school with good grades and due to some unavoidable reasons can’t go to university. Currently, I am self-studying mathematics. My interests include single and multi-variable calculus, linear algebra, probability, discrete mathematics and graph theory.

I have few books on these subjects. For example: Apostol’s and Spivak’s calculus books, Ross probability etc.

My problem is I read theory from these books and try to solve exercise questions, but when I can’t find solutions to a problem I have nowhere to look for step-by-step explanation to that problem. Most of the books I have don’t have detailed explanations or solution manuals.

And as live on the remotest part of a developing country, I have no teacher and professors to ask questions.  And I have tried Chegg subscription but most of the solutions they have are disappointing and cryptic if not downright horrible.

How should I deal with this situation? I really want to learn math. Please help me.

Comment: I think this site is perfect for your needs. If you encounter problems when solving the exercises You can just post a question here, show your attempts and explain where you got stuck. Of course this doesn't change the fact that it is hard to self-study mathematics.. I wish You good success!

Comment: There is an "Answer Book" for Spivak, and perhaps for some of your other texts as well. If you can obtain them, they might be useful in addition to MSE and other resources. https://www.amazon.com/dp/0914098926/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_i_YVcKFbK5J6EDQ

Comment: You have the internet and Math Stack exchange. Ask us! :) I am sorry to hear about your situation. Maybe try contacting a professor online?